# Multithreading Python3 whit Sql-Injection

Tags: python, multithreading

Good afternoon, I have a question that I cannot solve. I want to do a SQL injection in Hack The Box (Legal Platform). The case is that I am trying to execute a query to the server, if the query is valid, the server takes two seconds to return the response.
To speed this up, I want to do it with threads... The problem comes because if I try to do it with the threading module, it doesn't work correctly for me, the order in which the threads start and finish is important. I show you an example:

```
from threading import Thread

import time

import string


def prueba(a):

    if a in letras:
        time.sleep(2)
        letras_agregadas.append(a)



letras_agregadas = []

progreso = ""

letras = ["a", "k", "s", "C", "F", "Z"]

antes = time.time()

for letra in string.ascii_letters:

    h1 = Thread(target=prueba, args=(letra,))

    h1.start()

resultado = "".join(letras_agregadas)

despues = time.time()

print("".join(letras_agregadas) + "antes")

print(resultado)

print(antes - despues)
```

I would like the "resultado" variable to obtain the letters in the order it was received, but the program ends and does not add anything to "resultado", I have tried with .join() but then the program takes the same time as without using Thread , Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: "I have tried with .join()" *Where* in the code did you ``join``?

Comment: Note that if you are generally trying to run an operation concurrent, `concurrent.futures` offers a much better and fool-proof interface than raw `threading`. A `ThreadPoolExecutor.map` looks like what you want.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try that library, thank you very much, I'll look for information and try it that way.

In that part of the code there is no join(), since it didn't offer me what I wanted, I'm going to try another way.

Thank you very much, greetings.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `multiprocessing` and running everything with `Pool`, which allows you patallelize across multiple variables.

Here's how I did it:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
def prueba(a):
    letras_agregadas = []
    if a in letras:
        time.sleep(2)
        letras_agregadas.append("".join(a+'antes'))
    return letras_agregadas


progreso = ""

letras = ["a", "k", "s", "C", "F", "Z"]

antes = time.time()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(5) as p:
        h1 = p.map(prueba, letras)
        print(h1)
```

The output:

```
['aantes'], ['kantes'], ['santes'], ['Cantes'], ['Fantes'], ['Zantes']
```

Additionally - there is some confusion with what you are trying to achieve. For example, why are you doing this `print("".join(letras_agregadas) + "antes")`, and then you haves `antes = time.time()` as a `time` action.